# Extending Axis Code Generation module

Tags: java, templates, code-generation, apache-axis

In short, what I'm looking to achieve is the ability to run wsdl2java and generate extra code. Has anyone done this and can offer hints/tips/advice, has anyone done anything similar with a different approach the one outline further down the question (a lot further down)?

In the long form:

**Background:**

We have a third party piece of software that is used extensively in many projects but it has no ability to integrate directly with web services. With this in mind we take the wsdl, generate the client and then have a lot of boilerplate code that sits on top to allow integration. I've spent some time stream lining this but I want to go the whole hog.

**Current standing:**

I've written a simple first generation code generator which handles the creation of 95% of the code however this is reads in a hand written xml config, outputs the code using FileWriter(eugh), but I still need to hand write the code to tie it pass info to/from the actual webservice client code. This was just a quick and dirty solution as I needed it fast, and also to act as a POC.

**Approach to solving this:**
I'm picking this up in my own time purely because I think its a interesting problem but as such I don't want to waste lots of it on a dead end approach.

I believe the way to achieve my goal is to write an extension to the code generation module as described here http://wso2.org/library/35, I belive by writing this extension I will get access to the axis model of the wsdl and can apply my own xslt to it.

If you agree and have done similar, is there any advice you care to share, or useful resources you can point me to.

If you disagree with my approach I'd appreciate a brief outline( don't want to waste your time) of why and suggestion for a new approch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further research revealed that the way to go was to create a new CodeEmitter based on  AxisServiceBasedMultiLanguageEmitter.

Unfortunately this project was canned as there stopped being a requirement to create the web service clients. The third party piece of software released a new version allowing it to directly consume web services.

Answer (score 0):

I have never extended the Axis2 WSDL2Java emitter so I don't know how much flexibility you would gain from doing so. The article you reference suggests that you can hook into the generation process quite easily. It really depends on what you have to generate.
Recently I had to do create boilerplate code from Database schemas and WSDLs and I have used a mixed approach:

- Groovy

Groovy is great for rapid prototyping and templates. You can, for instance, collect information from a Database or a Wsdl and emit code based on a template. Here you can see some examples: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Templates

- PMD API

[PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) is a tool to scan Java code and report potential problems. It also exposes an API for parsing code using XPATH and has a very rich model to work with. You can do stuff like:

```
final Java15Parser parser = new Java15Parser();
final FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream("VehicleServiceType.java");

final Object c = parser.parse(new InputStreamReader(stream));

final XPath xpath = new BaseXPath("//TypeDeclaration/Annotation/NormalAnnotation[Name/@Image = 'WebService']",
        new DocumentNavigator());

for (final Iterator iter = xpath.selectNodes(c).iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
   final Object obj = iter.next();
      // Do code generation based on annotations...
}
```

Personally, I have found that a mixed approach works better then a monolithic one. Code generation is often an art more then a science. 
One more thing: in my current project, I'm looking at Python for (simple) code generation. It has a very nice templating library ([jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/)), but I wouldn't recommend it for parsing Java code.

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

You've already started writing a code generator to achieve your end so you could try continuing on this path. The codemodel library is a pretty amazing library for generating code. I have just recently used it to generate code and it was very good.

I'd suggest you give this codemodel library a try to generate the code you require. This is the codemodel library written for jaxb wsdl to java compiler.

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look that.

Answer (score 0):

We've used wsdl2java a lot (but in axis 1.4) My only tips are:

1 use complex/structured types as the arguments to operations e.g. resetWidget(widgetStruct) where widgetStruct class contains the fields widgetId, widgetName, widgetType etc instead of resetWidget(arg1, arg2, arg3..). So next year when you extend the WSDL and add some more params all the legacy code will still compile without have to extend all your methods. This approach was actually forced on us because another (old) WSDL tool didn't generate the responses correctly if we passed all the fields as params.

2 Put all you business logic into other classes. So when you regenerate the skeleton you can just put back in a few lines of code instead of having to update huge chunks of code.

Maybe some of these problems are solved in Axis2.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, and I may be mis-reading it, but it sounds like you use wsdl2java as is, you've not actually extended it's code generation funcitonality to do more than generate the skeletons.